# Add plane boundary point on touch ARCore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am working with ARCore in Unity and would like to be able to add points to ARCore's boundary plane by touching a point on the screen. Is this possible?

More specifically, I want to be able to touch a point on the screen that I think should be part of ARCore's current plane and have that point be added to the plane's mesh.

I've looked around a bit through their documentation and on stackoverflow and haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: I think you would have to edit the procedurally generated mesh from the point cloud data generated by the device.

Answer (score 0):

This is not able and there is a grand chance that this will never be able.

Reason:
AR works with 3D reality, so it not a 2D dimension. This said when you click on your screen how the app will know how far you wanna click?

If the app is not recognising the plane it will have difficult to know if your click is for 30cm from the screen or 2m from the screen or 35cm from the screen.

Got the problem? if the app know the distance for sure it can decide by itself if is a plane.

The solution would be "put" fiscally the app in places that you wanna build a plane, like 3 coordinates and crate a plane between then. But this is not in the direction for User Experience with AR, so I expected today that no one will stop to do something like...